# How can I search within a listview of json objects?

Tags: java, android, json, listview, retrofit

I have a listview populated with json objects fetched from a URL using retrofit.

Every object has a detail page that is displayed when clicked on the object.

How can search for objects in the listview and by clicking on the result the correct object with its detail page is displayed?

I already tried searchview with what I assume is only a filter not a real search, because it only shows me the objects matching my inserted search string but when I click on a filtered object it still gives me the item originally listed on that position.

public class SearchTafelnActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
SearchView sv;



private List<TafelnCall> tafelItems;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ProgressBar progressBar;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    handleIntent(intent);
}

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.pBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    handleIntent(getIntent());


    /*final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
    searchView.setIconified(true);


    searchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchView.setIconified(false);
        }
    });*/





        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.bot_nav);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(navigation);//Dont forgot this line

        Menu menu = navigation.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuitem = menu.getItem(3);
        menuitem.setChecked(true);

    //Switch activities
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch(item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_home:

                     Intent intent0 = new Intent(SearchTafelnActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent0);
                    break;

                    case R.id.nav_news:

                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(SearchTafelnActivity.this, NewsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_money:

                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(SearchTafelnActivity.this, DonateActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_search:

                    /*Intent intent3 = new Intent(SearchTafelnActivity.this, SearchTafelnActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);*/
                        break;


                }
                return false;
            }
        });



        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TafelnCall tafelitem = tafelItems.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(SearchTafelnActivity.this, TafelDetailPage.class);

                String tName = tafelitem.getName();
                String tAdress = tafelitem.getAddress();
                String tContact = tafelitem.getContactPerson();
                String tPhone = tafelitem.getPhone1();
                String tMail = tafelitem.getEmail();
                String tLong = tafelitem.getLongitude();
                String tLat = tafelitem.getLatitude();
                String tStreet = tafelitem.getAddress();
                String tZip = tafelitem.getZip();

                intent.putExtra( "key_tName", tName);
                intent.putExtra( "key_tAdress", tAdress);
                intent.putExtra( "key_tContact", tContact);
                intent.putExtra( "key_tPhone", tPhone);
                intent.putExtra( "key_tMail", tMail);
                intent.putExtra("key_tLong", tLong );
                intent.putExtra("key_tLat", tLat);
                intent.putExtra("key_tStreet", tStreet);
                intent.putExtra("key_tZip", tZip);


                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

        Call<List<TafelnCall>> call = api.getTafeln();



        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<TafelnCall>>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<TafelnCall>> call, Response<List<TafelnCall>> response) {

                tafelItems = response.body();

                final String [] tafelNames = new String[tafelItems.size()];

                for(int i =0; i< tafelItems.size(); i++){
                    final TafelnCall tafelnCall = tafelItems.get(i);
                    tafelNames[i] = tafelnCall.getName();
                  /*tafelNames[i] = tafelnCall.getAddress();
                    tafelNames[i] = tafelnCall.getAddressAdd();
                    tafelNames[i] = tafelnCall.getCarrier();
                    tafelNames[i] = tafelnCall.getCategory();
                    tafelNames[i] = tafelnCall.getCity();*/




                }

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        R.layout.listitem,
                        tafelNames
                );

                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                //Search function start
                sv = findViewById(R.id.searchView);
                sv.setQueryHint("Suche");
                sv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        sv.setIconified(false); //makes whole searchview clickable
                    }
                });


                sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(text);



                        return false;
                    }
                });



                ////Search function end



            }



            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<TafelnCall>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fehler beim Laden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        });


    }
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        //use the query to search your data somehow
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I apply the filter directly to the ListView, not to the adapter... these are my overrides:

```
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        breedListView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        breedListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
        breedListView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        breedListView.setFilterText(query.toString());
    }
    return false;
}
```

My breedListView is the same as your listView

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
// Here is how you would do it
listView.setFilterText(query.toString());
```

Here are some of the settings

```
public class DogGuideFragment extends ListFragment
    …
private ListView breedListView;
… 
//In a ListFragment, getListView() gets the main ListView of the Fragment
breedListView = getListView();
breedListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    breedListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
…
//setListAdapter is a method of a ListFragment that sets the data for the ListView
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(thisContext,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listOfBreeds));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe this is my problem that I dont directly apply to the listView. How do I directly apply to the listviiew? 
I dont quite understand what "breedListView" does. Couldnt find any good hints via google. :(